# Angles between vectors of center of two incircles

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, rectangles

I have two two incircle between rectangle and two 
quadrilateral circlein. It's possible to determine exact value of $\phi,$ angles between vectors of center of two circles.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Place the origin $O$ at the lower left-hand corner, and let the positive $x,y$-axes be the the natural choices based on the diagram.

Let $r$ be the radius of the red circles.

Let $P,Q$ be the centers of the circles of radii $2,1$, respectively.

Then we can express the coordinates of $P,Q$ as $P=(x,2)$ and $Q=(x,r-1)$, where $x$ is an unknown.

Computing $|OQ|$ in two ways, we get the equation
$$\sqrt{x^2+(r-1)^2}=r+1$$
hence
$$x^2+(r-1)^2=(r+1)^2\tag{eq1}$$
Computing $|OP|$ in two ways, we get the equation
$$\sqrt{x^2+2^2}=r-2$$
hence
$$x^2+4=(r-2)^2\tag{eq2}$$
From $(\text{eq}1){\,-\,}(\text{eq}2)$, we get $r=8$.

Plugging $r=8$ into $(\text{eq}2)$, we get $x=4\sqrt{2}$.

Using the known values of $r$ and $x$, the distance formula yields
\begin{align*}
|OP|&=6\\[4pt]
|OQ|&=9\\[4pt]
|PQ|&=5\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence by the law of cosines, $\cos(\large{\phi})={\large{\frac{23}{27}}}$, so we get $\large{\phi}=\cos^{-1}\bigl({\large{\frac{23}{27}}}\bigr)$.

Comment: that's slick!..

Comment: How could I set multiple answers as correct response?

Comment: @BarzanHayati: You can upvote multiple answers, but you can't accept more than one answer. If you like another answer better than the one you've accepted, it's ok to unaccept and accept the other.

Answer (score 2):

There are constraints that $A$ and $B$ must fullfill, i.e., the following system of equations coming from Pythagoras theorem applied to certain right triangles :

$$\begin{cases}(B-2)^2+2^2=(A/2)^2\\(B-1)^2+(A/2)^2=(B+1)^2\end{cases}$$

giving $A=8 \sqrt{2}$ and $B=8$.

If now we take equations as in the partial solution you gave (a good idea) :

$$\tan(\theta) = \dfrac{2}{A/2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\tag{1}$$

and

$$\tan(\phi + \theta) = \dfrac{B-1}{A/2} = \dfrac{7}{4 \sqrt{2}}\tag{2}$$

Equation (2) can also be written :

$$\dfrac{\tan(\phi) + \tan(\theta)}{1-\tan(\phi)\tan(\theta)} = \dfrac{7\sqrt{2}}{8}\tag{3}$$

Let $T:=\tan(\phi)$. (3) is equivalent to :

$$\dfrac{T + \sqrt{2}/4}{1-T\sqrt{2}/4} = \dfrac{7\sqrt{2}}{8}\tag{4}$$

giving $T=\dfrac{10 \sqrt{2}}{23}$. Therefore

> > $\phi=\arctan(\dfrac{10 \sqrt{2}}{23})\approx 31.5863 \ \text{degrees}.$

Comment: It would be great if you add your answer.

Comment: How could I set multiple answers as correct response?

Comment: On this site, it is not possible to check more than one answer...

Answer (score 2):

Using Pythagoras theorem is not difficult to find that the radius $B$ of red arcs is $8$. It follows that $PQ=6$, $PR=9$ and $QR=5$. Apply now the cosine rule to triangle $PQR$ to find 
$$
\cos\phi={23\over27}.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let $|AB|=|CD|=a$,$|BC|=|AD|=b$,
$|O_1E|=r_1$,
$|O_2F|=r_2$,
$\angle O_1AO_2=\phi$,
$\angle O_1AF=\alpha$
$\angle O_2AF=\beta$.

Then
\begin{align}
\tan\alpha&=\frac{b-r_1}{a/2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\sin\alpha&=\frac{b-r_1}{b+r_1}
,\\
\tan\alpha&=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}}
=\frac{b-r_1}{b+r_1}
\left/
\sqrt{1-\Big( \frac{b-r_1}{b+r_1} \Big)^2} \right.
=\tfrac12\,\frac{b-r_1}{\sqrt{b\,r_1}}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

From \eqref{1}$=$\eqref{2} it follows
\begin{align}
a&=4\,\sqrt{b\,r_1}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Similarly,
\begin{align}
\tan\beta&=\frac{2r_2}a
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\sin\beta&=\frac{r_2}{b-r_2}
,\\
\tan\beta&=
\frac{\sin\beta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\beta}}
=\frac{r_2}{\sqrt{b\,(b-2\,r_2)}}
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

From \eqref{4}$=$\eqref{5}:
\begin{align}
a&=2\,\sqrt{b\,(b-2\,r_2)}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

and from \eqref{3}$=$\eqref{6}
we have

\begin{align}
b&=4r_1+2r_2
,\\
a&=4\,\sqrt{r_1\,(4\,r_1+2\,r_2)}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\tan\phi&=\tan(\alpha-\beta)
=\frac{\tan\alpha-\tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}
=\frac{2(3r_1+r_2)\,\sqrt{2\,r_1\,(2\,r_1+r_2)}}{16\,r_1^2+11\,r_1\,r_2+2\,r_2^2}
\end{align}

For $r_1=1$, $r_2=2$ we have

\begin{align}
a&=8\,\sqrt2\approx 11.31370850
,\\
b&=8
,\\
\phi&=\arctan\Big(\frac{10\,\sqrt2}{23} \Big)
\approx 31.586338^\circ
.
\end{align}

Comment: How could I set multiple answers as correct response?